# External USB Bluetooth does not work in Android 4.0.4 kernel 3.0.8+

Tags: bluetooth, usb-drivers

I have inserted an external USB Bluetooth dongle into a Tablet via the USB port and try to turn on the Bluetooth in the Android but fail.

So, how does one know if the USB Bluetooth dongle can be supported for a tablet that has a USB port? (Given that the USB Bluetooth dongle has been tested to work fine in a desktop PC and there is no further information on the tablet manual on which Bluetooth dongle is supported for the tablet.)

This is the problem with all tablets which do not have in-built Bluetooth support.

Is there any application that can compile/root/install Bluetooth device driver to my Android tablet so that I can use it for headphones/file transfer, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Android supports external Bluetooth adapters. From [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/115049428938715274412/posts/4b3X4di33Lm), it seems like CyanogenMod is adding support for it soon. Depending on what device you have, you may be able to root and install this.

If this is not an option, then you would need to provide more details on what device you are trying to use the dongle with.